# How to get list of applied templates using WLST

Tags: weblogic, wlst, appserver

I have an existing weblogic domain. I want to get a list of domain creation and extention templates which have already been added to that domain. [using **addTemplate()** WLST command ] .
Is there a way to do that though WLST?
I am new to weblogic and WLST and would appreciate any help.

The templates which have been already added to domain, their information is maintained in **$DOMAIN_HOME/init-info/domain-info.xml**. But I would rather get it through WLST than using file parsing on this .xml .

If someone can suggest a solution where we can browse to some diectory in domain tree [ after doing **readDomain()**] which will have applied template information, this will solve my purpose.

I have gone though WLST command reference : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/web.1111/e13813/reference.htm#i1155751
But there is no template information related command.

Thanks in advance for response !

Answer (score 2):

'showTemplates()' will do the trick. First read the domain using readDomain command and then use showTemplates.

```
wls:/offline>readDomain(<Absolute path to DOMAIN_DIR>)
wls:/offline/<domain_name>>showTemplates()
```